# Combine two grids in Mathematica

Tags: grid-layouts

I have the following data

```
DATA1={{1,-70.54,-70.54,-70.54,2875.63,203.21,40946.81,2298.26,0.19,0.0022,0.96,11.,88.29,2060.,-0.00404,-2050.,0.0103},{2,-75.16,-75.16,-75.16,2790.36,20.759,20685.47,468.783,0.16,0.022,0.98,79.,447.5,130.,-0.612,15.3,71.4},{3,-74.36,-74.36,-74.36,2995.82,206.31,66549.29,2880.45,0.21,0.0012,0.046,15.,77.35,24.5,-0.376,2.44,87.5},{4,-73.98,-73.98,-73.98,2957.59,204.08,43170.78,2829.02,0.23,0.0018,0.078,21.,77.36,43.3,-0.817,7.68,80.0},{5,-82.51,-82.51,-82.51,2963.79,538.94,50524.51,5376.89,0.25,0.00090,0.048,13.,45.47,6.89,1.,-1.21,9.65},{6,-83.78,-83.78,-83.78,2694.16,429.32,79162.48,4369.53,0.24,0.00065,0.030,15.,51.64,4.50*10^(6),-6.35*10^(-7),-4.50*10^(6),0.0000204},{7,-75.72,-75.72,-75.72,2949.44,213.08,77672.58,2071.73,0.23,0.0014,0.070,44.,107.8,5.05*10^(6),8.44*10^(-7),-5.05*10^(6),0.0000433}};
DATA2={{1,-74.01,-74.01,-74.01,2939.66,191.54,2169.407,2135.48,0.22,0.047,0.31,92.,101.9,-84.9,-4.7,80.9,-363.},{2,-75.19,-75.19,-75.19,792.686,0.69101,931.1111,83.5431,0.78,0.77,0.92,78.,713.4,32.4,-1.28,68.3,60.0},{3,-78.77,-78.77,-78.77,2832.86,281.89,66859.41,2414.00,0.24,0.0014,0.21,25.,92.41,39.4,-1.30,3.81,22.9},{4,-80.81,-80.81,-80.81,2913.93,234.38,37534.88,2223.32,0.23,0.0028,0.14,20.,105.9,46.9,-1.38,-0.510,73.1},{5,-76.29,-76.29,-76.29,2972.13,203.95,39781.13,1883.95,0.23,0.0030,0.094,21.,120.4,147.,-2.59,-1.97,107.},{6,-78.18,-78.18,-78.18,2992.97,213.32,38167.21,1777.47,0.25,0.0034,0.096,23.,131.7,93.7,-1.91,-2.94,49.9},{7,-75.59,-75.59,-75.59,2311.95,375.80,93875.21,3315.32,0.24,0.00056,0.018,6.3,52.69,183.,-0.0709,-169.,0.188},{8,-69.11,-69.11,-69.11,2980.73,598.49,72226.15,7143.61,0.24,0.00040,0.24,0.28,28.84,0.956,0.411,0.149,264.},{9,-68.97,-68.97,-68.97,2679.44,394.60,28449.60,7348.71,0.13,0.00088,0.037,14.,25.16,37.6,-0.890,-0.109,32.4},{10,-69.5,-69.5,-69.5,2871.99,415.67,15755.71,5069.04,0.24,0.0025,0.024,1.6,39.38,64.8,-3.33,-0.658,25.0}};
```

I construct the following grids

```
GRID1=Grid[Prepend[Prepend[DATA1,{Style["#",Bold],Style["Subscript[E, L]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, r]",Bold],Style["Cm",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[\[Tau], m]",Bold],Style["K",Bold],Style["\[Beta]",Bold],Style["\[Delta]",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep]^start",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep0]",Bold],Style["\[Tau]",Bold],Style["a",Bold],Style["b",Bold],Style["c",Bold],Style["d",Bold]}],{Style["DATI 1",Bold],SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft}],Background->{None,{Lighter[Blue,.9],Lighter[Blue,.9],{White,Lighter[Gray,.8]}}},Dividers->{{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],{Lighter[Gray,.5]},Darker[Gray,.6]},{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],Darker[Gray,.6],{False},Darker[Gray,.6]}},Alignment->{{Center,Center,Center}},ItemSize->{All},Frame->Darker[Gray,.6],ItemStyle->14,Spacings->{1,1}];
GRID2=Grid[Prepend[Prepend[DATA2,{Style["#",Bold],Style["Subscript[E, L]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, r]",Bold],Style["Cm",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[\[Tau], m]",Bold],Style["K",Bold],Style["\[Beta]",Bold],Style["\[Delta]",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep]^start",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep0]",Bold],Style["\[Tau]",Bold],Style["a",Bold],Style["b",Bold],Style["c",Bold],Style["d",Bold]}],{Style["DATI 2",Bold],SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft}],Background->{None,{Lighter[Blue,.9],Lighter[Blue,.9],{White,Lighter[Gray,.8]}}},Dividers->{{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],{Lighter[Gray,.5]},Darker[Gray,.6]},{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],Darker[Gray,.6],{False},Darker[Gray,.6]}},Alignment->{{Center,Center,Center}},ItemSize->{All},Frame->Darker[Gray,.6],ItemStyle->14,Spacings->{1,1}];
```

I would like to combine these two GRID together, namely one up and the other down in order to form one single table.

Comment: we should replace `"Subscript[E, L]"`  by `Subscript[E, L]` etc.

Comment: Is this only for display purposes? For instance is `Grid[{{GRID1}, {GRID2}}, Alignment -> {Left, Left}, Frame -> All]` what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to obtain something like that

[image]

Of course I would like also that each column have also the same size. I would like to keep the blue background parts as they are in the above picture.

The solution I have found is to insert in GRID1 and GRID2 in ItemSize the same numbers, namely

```
GRID1=Grid[Prepend[Prepend[DATA1,{Style["#",Bold],Style["Subscript[E, L]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, r]",Bold],Style["Cm",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[\[Tau], m]",Bold],Style["K",Bold],Style["\[Beta]",Bold],Style["\[Delta]",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep]^start",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep0]",Bold],Style["\[Tau]",Bold],Style["a",Bold],Style["b",Bold],Style["c",Bold],Style["d",Bold]}],{Style["DATI 1",Bold],SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft}],Background->{None,{Lighter[Blue,.9],Lighter[Blue,.9],{White,Lighter[Gray,.8]}}},Dividers->{{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],{Lighter[Gray,.5]},Darker[Gray,.6]},{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],Darker[Gray,.6],{False},Darker[Gray,.6]}},Alignment->{{Center,Center,Center}},ItemSize->{{2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7}, 1},Frame->Darker[Gray,.6],ItemStyle->14,Spacings->{1,1}];
GRID2=Grid[Prepend[Prepend[DATA2,{Style["#",Bold],Style["Subscript[E, L]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[V, r]",Bold],Style["Cm",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, th]",Bold],Style["Subscript[\[Tau], m]",Bold],Style["K",Bold],Style["\[Beta]",Bold],Style["\[Delta]",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep]^start",Bold],Style["Subscript[I, dep0]",Bold],Style["\[Tau]",Bold],Style["a",Bold],Style["b",Bold],Style["c",Bold],Style["d",Bold]}],{Style["DATI 2",Bold],SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft}],Background->{None,{Lighter[Blue,.9],Lighter[Blue,.9],{White,Lighter[Gray,.8]}}},Dividers->{{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],{Lighter[Gray,.5]},Darker[Gray,.6]},{Black,Darker[Gray,.6],Darker[Gray,.6],{False},Darker[Gray,.6]}},Alignment->{{Center,Center,Center}},ItemSize->{{2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7}, 1},Frame->Darker[Gray,.6],ItemStyle->14,Spacings->{1,1}];
```

And after

```
Grid[{{GRID1},{GRID2}},Alignment->{Left,Left}]
```

Comment: Isn't this what @bmf proposed earlier?

Comment: Yes almost, I changed in GRID1 and GRID2 the ItemSize, as you can see comparing my last version (ItemSize->{{2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7}, 1}) with that posted initially (ItemSize->{All}).